# removing multiple movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm developing a game.I've attached random movieClips from library.  I've movieClips named `picLeft1`, `picLeft2`, `picLeft3` and so on in library.  Its working fine but i'm having problem removing it.  the code below is for the attachment of movieclip.  Here `ranque` is an array which stores randomly generated numbers up to 5 and `HolderL` is the movieClip in which I want to attach the movieClip.  And `q` is a sprite.

```
for (var i:int = 0; int<3; i++) {    
    que_mc.push("picLeft"+ranque[i]);    
    var que_mc_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(que_mc[i]) as Class;   
    q = new que_mc_class();  
    this["HolderL"+(i+1)].addChild(q);  
}
```

my code for removing the movieclip is given below.I want to remove all the movieclip attached in `HolderL`. but this code is not working.

```
for(var j:int = 1; j<=3; j++) {  
    this["HolderL"+j].removeChild(q);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Flash Player 11 allows you to use this:

```
for (var j:int = 1; j<=3; j++) {  
    var container : DisplayObjectContainer = this["HolderL"+j];
    container.removeChildren();
}
```

Earlier versions don't have the `removeChildren()` command; you have to have two loops: One to loop to iterate over the container movie clips, one to traverse the display list and remove all children.

Shortest way to remove all children of a container prior to FlashPlayer 11:

```
while (container.numChildren > 0) container.removeChildAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your code what `q` is, but basically if you want to remove all the children from one movie clip, the simplest is to loop through all the children and remove them one by one. For example:

```
for (var i:int = container.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    container.removeChildAt(i);
}
```

Comment: For Flash Player 11 there's this possibility too: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChildren%28%29